# jooq 3.11.9 with MySQL Ver 8.0.11

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jooq

I am using jooq version 3.11.9 and I have MySQL Ver 8.0.11 installed on my local. While initiating connection of jooq with Mysql I get the following error:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select 1 as `one` from dual where exists (select 1 as `one` from `mysql`.`proc`)]; Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
```

I understand MySQL Ver 8.0.11 doesn't contain this table. So what is the solution? I cannot downgrade the MySQL versions as other projects are already running with this version.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the mysql [Release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-0.html):

> Previously, information about stored routines and events was stored in the proc and event tables of the mysql system database. Those tables are no longer used. Instead, information about stored routines and events is stored in the routines, events, and parameters data dictionary tables in the mysql system database. The old tables used the MyISAM (nontransactional) storage engine. The new tables use the InnoDB (transactional) engine.

Comment: It says `mysql.proc` doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the solution then? Should I downgrade?

Comment: @HarshitGupta It is hard to say without seeing your config and where the Statement is comming from

Answer (score 0):

That query is there precisely to check whether you're running on MySQL 8+. It should not cause an error or even a stack trace (but maybe a debug message). You can safely ignore it.

If you found an error or stack trace message, or if this causes your code generation to fail, it might be a bug in jOOQ's logging configuration, which I would invite you to file here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new

Comment: Hi Lukas, so my application was indeed failing to start with a stack trace message. So I have files an issue at Github. Thanks a lot